# ExtJs Tree Store and data pull

Tags: php, html, mysql, extjs, tree

My data in database

[image]

Currently my php file is reading data from database like

```
        $data = array();

        $sql = "SELECT * FROM tree";

        $q = mysql_query($sql);

        while ($r = mysql_fetch_array($q)) {
            // check if have a child node                           
            $qq = mysql_query("SELECT `id`, `text` FROM `tree` WHERE parent_id = '". $r['id'] ."'");

            if (mysql_num_rows($qq) > 0) {
                // if have a child
                $r['leaf'] = false;
                $r['cls'] = 'folder';
            } else {
                // if have no child
                $r['leaf'] = true;
                $r['cls'] = 'file';
            }
            $data[] = $r;

        }               


        echo json_encode($data);
    ?>
    <div id="tree_el"></div>
```

My JavaScript is

```
    Ext.require([
        'Ext.tree.*',
        'Ext.data.*',
        'Ext.tip.*'
    ]);

    Ext.onReady(function() {
        Ext.QuickTips.init();

        var store = Ext.create('Ext.data.TreeStore', {
            proxy: {
                type: 'ajax',
                url: 'treegetdata.php'
            },
            root: {
                text: 'Eatables',
                id: 'root_node',
                expanded: true
            },
            folderSort: true,
            sorters: [{
                property: 'text',
                direction: 'ASC'
            }]
        });

        var tree = Ext.create('Ext.tree.Panel', {
            store: store,
            renderTo: 'tree_el',
            height: 300,
            width: 250,
            title: 'Eatables'
        });
    });
```

My current result looks like this

[image]

My expected result should be

[image]

There is issue while I pull data from database. Please help me fix it so the expected format is achieved. I believe the fix is required in my php file.

Comment: Can't see your current result.

Comment: This will be very inefficient. Better fetch all the results at once and use a recursive algo on the results to generate the tree. Shouldn't query the db so many times.

Comment: @VarunAchar Can you please help with snippet?

Answer (score 1):

OK I see your problem, your format of your returned JSON is wrong.
If you want the children to be in the parent you need to actually give them back in the parent's children collection like this:

```
{
   children: [{
       name: 'Eatables',
       children: [{
            name: 'Fruits',
            children: [...]
       }, {
            name: 'Vegetables' ,
            children: [...]
       }]
   }]
}
```

This is what you give back now:

```
[{
    name: 'Apples',
    leaf: false,
    cls: 'folder'
},{
    name: 'Eatables',
    leaf: false,
    cls: 'folder'
},{
    name: 'Fruits',
    leaf: false,
    cls: 'folder'
},{
    name: 'Vegetables',
    leaf: false,
    cls: 'folder'
},{
    name: 'Gala apples',
    leaf: false,
    cls: 'file'
}, ....
]
```

So it's very logical that ExtJS sees them all as level 1 nodes. Instead of making multiple levels.

The problem lies indeed in the PHP file.

Answer (score 0):

There is a logical error while generating the tree that has to be fed to extjs. I don't know PHP so i'll write javascript:

```
function getTree()
{
    var tree, list = [], root, result = []; // fetch list from database
    tree = {text : root.name};
    result.push(createTreeStructur(tree, root, list));
    return result;
}
    //tree = holder of data, root = parent in each recursive call, list = complete list from database
    function createTreeStructure(tree, root, list) {
       var i=0, ln = children.length, result = [], child, childList = [], temptree = {};
       var children = getChildren(root, list); //Fetch children
       for(i=0, i<ln;i++)
       {
          child = children[i];
          tree = [];
          if(getChildren(child, list).length===0) //If no children of child exist
          {
             temptree = {name : child.name, leaf : true};
             childList.push(temptree);
             tree["children"] = childList; // Add child as child of the passed parent
          }
          else
          {
             temptree = {name : child.name, leaf : false}; 
             childList.push(temptree);
             tree["children"] = childList;
             createTreeStructure(temptree, child, list); // Recursively create tree structure for the child since children exist.
          }
       }
      result.push(tree);
      return result;
    }

    function getChildren(root, list)
    {
       var i=0, ln = list.length, result = [];
       for(i=0, i<ln;i++)
       {
          if(root.id===list[i].parent)
          {
             result.push(list[i]);
          }
       }
       return result;
    }
```